# How to convert select & options to Laravel Form Elements

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have the following select section in HTML and CSS taken from ADMIN LTE

```
<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska</option>
    <option>California</option>
    <option>Delaware</option>
    <option>Tennessee</option>
    <option>Texas</option>
    <option>Washington</option>
</select>
```

I need to convert it to Laravel Form Elements and I tried as follows:

```
{{Form::select('filter_region', [
    '1' => 'Alaska', 
    '2' => 'California',
    '3' => 'Delaware',
], null, ['placeholder' => 'Alaska'],['class'=>'form-control select2'])}}
```

But the views are different

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: Combine the last two arrays in `Form::select` into one

Comment: Add `select2` cdn in blade

Comment: @apokryfos it works. Thanks ;)